# Fluentd - Not able to connect to SQL server using windows authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fluentd

I'm able to successfully connect to SQL server using SQL SERVER AUTHENTICATION however it does not work with WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION, is it a bug, or I'm missing something in the configuration?

```
<source>
  @type sql
  host HOSTNAME
  database db_name
  adapter sqlserver
  username WindowsUser
  password WindowsPwd
  <table>
    table tbl_name
    update_column insert_timestamp
  </table>
</source>

<match **>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

I get below error:

```
[warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=1 next_retry_seconds=2021-09-01 22:12:40 238620126384680326147/703687441776640000000 +0530 chunk="5caf1c0f1dfbb6d0ca989ce4ffd28fa3" error_class=TinyTds::Error error="Adaptive Server connection failed (localhost)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, make sure to add a schema name with the table name.